# running a 3 to 7 Decoder using a counter

Tags: vhdl, hdl, cadence

I am trying to run my 3 to 7 decoder using the inputs coming from my counter ,all the individual codes run fine but the structural code is giving up some error

This is the program for my counter

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity counter is  
   port(clk , CLR : in std_logic;
   Q : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) );    
end counter;

architecture archi of counter is

    signal tmp: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);  

    begin      
    process (clk, CLR)   
         begin       

         if (CLR='1') then                  
             tmp <= "000";                       
         elsif (clk'event and clk='1') then  
              tmp <= tmp + 1;                     
          end if;        

     end process;   

     Q <= tmp;

 end archi;
```

---

**this is the program for the decoder:**

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity led_inp is

    port (I : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) ;

    L : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0) ) ;

end led_inp ;

architecture led_inp1 of led_inp is 

Begin    
    L(0) <= (not I(0)) and (not I(1)) and (not I(2));   
    L(1) <= (not I(0)) and (not I(1)) and I(2);
    L(2) <= (not I(0)) and I(1) and (not I(2));
    L(3) <= (not I(0)) and I(1) and I(2);
    L(4) <= I(0) and (not I(1)) and (not I(2));
    L(5) <= I(0) and (not I(1)) and I(2);
    L(6) <= I(0) and I(1) and (not I(2));
end led_inp1;
```

---

**this is the structural format for the whole design:**

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

-- the entity of the whole design block, here i have given the names of the ports as the ones which i have used in my individual components 

entity led_design is  
    port(clock,CLEAR :in std_logic;        
    L :out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0));   
end led_design; 

architecture led_design1 of led_design is 
-- declaring my counter as a component 
   component counter   
   port(clk, CLR : in std_logic;     
   Q : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) );
 end component ;

-- declaring my decoder as a component 

component led_inp 
    port (I : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) ;
    L : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)) ;
end component  ;

signal I:std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
begin 
    -- The PORT MAPPING BEGINS 

    L1: counter port map(clk=>clock,CLR=>CLEAR,I(2)=>I(2),I(1)=>I(1),I(0)=>I(0)); 

    L2: led_inp port map(I(2)=>I(2),I(1)=>I(1),I(0)=>I(0),L(0)=>L(0),L(1)=>L(1),L(2)=>L(2),L(3)=>L(3),L(4)=>L(4),L(5)=>L(5),L(6)=>L(6));

    L1: counter port 

    map(clk=>clock,CLR=>CLEAR,I(2)=>h(2),I(1)=>h(1),I(0)=>h(0)); 
end led_design1;
```

this is the error which comes up :ERROR
**ncvhdl_p: *E,FMLBAD (led_count,85|44): poorly formed formal part of element association 87[4.3.3.2] 93[4.3.2.2].
        errors: 1, warnings: 0"**

[image: schematic]

Comment: welcome @Justus, you should fix formating of your code (so it is well formated and highlighted), and explain what you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: @AdrieanKhisbe sorry me bad i am trying to instantiate a 3 to 7 decoder using  a counter

Comment: @DavidKoontz sorry for my mistake , the error i put up earlier was an old one which i copied by mistake ,forgive me for that .

Comment: led_count is indeed the file name !!

Comment: Some tips for next time @Justus, pay attention to the formating of the code. In Markdown, you just need four leading space. Space between the line where not that necessary. If you wanna know more about markdown formating, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help :)

Comment: @AdrieanKhisbe - i am really sorry !! this is my first post on stackoverflow and relatively a new HDL coder !! Sorry for the frustration casued

Comment: I'm not frustrated :)

Comment: Your image shows a 3 to 8 decoder and your declaration shows 3 to 7.  Also they decode the counter in the order 0,4,2,6,1,5,3. for counter values 0,1,2,3,4,5,6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the symbol `led_count` does not show up in your VHDL design description, is that the file name?

You have two labels L1 in led_design, it's also missing a declaration for signal h to match signal I. (which also tells you it's not used anywhere else).

Both `counter` association lists (port maps) don't match the component declaration. After fixing those things your code analyzes.  note `h` isn't used anywhere else.

Read the [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to format code, it's awful.

The lack of proper formatting and the inability to understand the error is preventing those who could answer from providing an answer.

Try this:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
--use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity counter is  
   port(clk , CLR : in std_logic;    
         Q : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) ); 
end counter;

architecture archi of counter is

    signal tmp: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);  

begin  

    process (clk, CLR)   
    begin       

        if (CLR='1') then                
            tmp <= "000";        
        elsif (clk'event and clk='1') then      
            tmp <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(tmp) + 1);             
        end if;        

    end process;   

    Q <= tmp;

end archi;



library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity led_inp is
    port (I : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) ;
          L : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0) ) ;
end led_inp ;

architecture led_inp1 of led_inp is 

Begin 

    L(0) <= (not I(0)) and (not I(1)) and (not I(2));
    L(1) <= (not I(0)) and (not I(1)) and I(2);
    L(2) <= (not I(0)) and I(1) and (not I(2));
    L(3) <= (not I(0)) and I(1) and I(2);
    L(4) <= I(0) and (not I(1)) and (not I(2));
    L(5) <= I(0) and (not I(1)) and I(2);
    L(6) <= I(0) and I(1) and (not I(2));

end led_inp1;



 library IEEE;
 use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

 entity led_design is 
     port(clock,CLEAR :in std_logic;    
          L :out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0));
 end led_design; 

 architecture led_design1 of led_design is

     component counter   
         port(clk, CLR : in std_logic;     
             Q : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) );
     end component ;

     component led_inp 
         port (I : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) ;
               L : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)) ;
     end component  ;

     signal I:std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
     signal h:std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
begin 

L1: counter port map (
      clk=>clock,CLR=>CLEAR, Q => I); -- I(2)=>I(2),I(1)=>I(1),I(0)=>I(0)); 

L2: led_inp port map ( I(2)=>I(2),I(1)=>I(1),I(0)=>I(0),L(0)=>L(0),L(1)=>L(1),L(2)=>L(2),L(3)=>L(3),L(4)=>L(4),L(5)=>L(5),L(6)=>L(6));

L3: counter port map( clk=>clock,CLR=>CLEAR, Q => h);-- I(2)=>h(2),I(1)=>h(1),I(0)=>h(0));
-- ERROR 
--**ncvhdl_p: *E,FMLBAD (led_count,85|44): poorly formed formal part of element association 87[4.3.3.2] 93[4.3.2.2].
--  errors: 1, warnings: 0"**


end led_design1;
```

The use clause for numeric_std and the type conversions is to enable me to use a -1993 compliant tool (which doesn't have std_logic_unsigned). Those changes are likely not required in your environment.

Notice the output of the second counter (connected to `h`) now labelled L3 does not go anywhere.

Notice the error should also show up in your line 83 if you simply fix line 85.

Comment: could u please look into it !!

Comment: i am sorry but the error i posted before was an earlier one !! i have updated the error which came to this design

Comment: I don't see any update "ERROR 
**ncvhdl_p: *E,FMLBAD (led_count,85|44): poorly formed formal part of element association 87[4.3.3.2] 93[4.3.2.2].
errors: 1, warnings: 0"**". It's still the same.  Please format the code in your question.

Comment: thanks it worked !! thanks a lot David !! i am sorry for all the irritating questions .I am absolutely new to stackoverflow and HDL programming